# Sorting Multidimensional array/vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I want to sort the array based on two values that are stored in elements sequ[i][2] and sequ[i][3].

If sequ[i][2] has similar values, it sorts it by sequ[i][3] value.

```
vector< vector<int> > sequ;
int m = 1024, n = 32;
sequ.resize(m);
for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i){
sequ[i].resize(n);
}
sort(sequ[0].begin(),sequ[0].end());
```

Unfortuantely i know only how to sort the array as a whole but not specific elements. How do i do this

Comment: I don't understand your problem but all the sorting methods provided with the C++ STL are included in the <algorithm> header http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm so just read them and see if there is something that is right for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had C++11 you should try something along these lines.

```
sort(  secu.begin(), secu.end(), [](const vector<int>&v1, const vector<int>&v2) -> bool
{
  return v1[2] < v2[2] || (v1[2] == v2[2] && (v1[3] < v2[3]) );
});
```

I'm not a super pro in C++11 lambda syntax, but you should get the idea. If you don't have C++11 you can always roll out your own comparison functor.

Answer (score 2):

The non-lambda method of doing this would be something like:

```
bool func(const vector<int> &v1, const vector<int> &v2)
{
    if(v1[2] < v2[2]) return true;
    if(v1[2] > v2[2]) return false;
    return v1[3] < v2[3];
}

...

sort(sequ.begin(),sequ.end(),func);
```